# How to set PowerPoint chart Point text labels to match marker colors?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In an X-Y scatter plot, I manually add text labels to data points via Point.DataLabel.  Unfortunately I find that when points are crowded then it can be difficult to tell which series a label belongs to.  Therefore I want to color my text labels to match the markers.

I am happy with the default markers and their colors, but unfortunately they contain MarkerForegroundColor = -1 and MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 0, no matter which series I look at.  Furthermore, Application.ActivePresentation.ColorSchemes is empty.  I note that point.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleAutomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the colors correspond to the accent colors in the active Theme (only available in PowerPoint 2007 onwards):

```
presentation.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex.msoThemeAccent1 + series_i % 6);
```